# Endpoint for getting GlobalValueSet using REST API

Tags: rest, global-picklist

I'm trying to use the REST API to get the list of values for a Global Value Set. Since it is not a field on a specific SObject, I don't think you can query for the values. I am successfully authenticated and have a valid REST call, but am getting a 404 response. I think it must have something to do with my endpoint I defined:

```
req.setEndpoint('https://'+host+'/services/data/v41.0/tooling/sobjects/GlobalValueSet/<myId>');
```

Is GlobalValueSet in the endpoint correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can query for GlobalValueSet via the Tooling API:

```
/services/data/v41.0/tooling/query?q=select+id+from+globalvalueset
```

And, if you had the right URL, you'd get a valid response:

```
/services/data/v41.0/tooling/sobjects/GlobalValueSet/0Nt..........
```

Make sure you use the full Id, should start with `0Nt`.

Response will be something like:

```
{
  "attributes" : {
    "type" : "GlobalValueSet",
    "url" : "/services/data/v41.0/tooling/sobjects/GlobalValueSet/0Nt....."
  },
  "Metadata" : {
    "customValue" : [ {
      "color" : null,
      "default" : false,
      "description" : null,
      "isActive" : null,
      "label" : "Yes",
      "urls" : null,
      "valueName" : "Yes"
    }, {
      "color" : null,
      "default" : false,
      "description" : null,
      "isActive" : null,
      "label" : "No",
      "urls" : null,
      "valueName" : "No"
    } ],
    "description" : null,
    "masterLabel" : "Value Label",
    "sorted" : false,
    "urls" : null
  },
  "FullName" : "Value_Label",
  "Id" : "0Nt...",
  "DeveloperName" : "Value_Label",
  "MasterLabel" : "Value Label",
  "Description" : null,
  "NamespacePrefix" : null,
  "ManageableState" : "unmanaged",
  "CreatedDate" : "2018-03-13T04:12:06.000+0000",
  "CreatedById" : "005........",
  "LastModifiedDate" : "2018-03-13T04:12:06.000+0000",
  "LastModifiedById" : "005........"
}
```

Comment: If I remove the Id at the end of the endpoint I get 200 and a valid response. But when I add the Id I get 404. I got the Id from the url when looking at the Global Value Set in setup. I tried both with and without the prefix 0Nt, I'm not sure why it's not working

Comment: @tom_12321 try running a query for it just to verify it's the right Id.

Comment: GlobalValueSet is not a valid SObject to query when doing an SOQL query. How would I query it?

Comment: @tom_12321 It's not a standard SOQL query, it's Tooling API query. [Different list of available objects](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/reference_objects_list.htm).

Comment: Oh ok, thanks for that link! How would I query for it? Would I do it in an anonymous apex window? Or would i do it in workbench somewhere?

Comment: @tom_12321 In the Developer Console in Salesforce, there's a Query tab. Type in your query and check the Use Tooling API checkbox. Or you can do so in the [Workbench](https://workbench.developerforce.com/login.php), using the example query in my answer.

Comment: I couldn't get it to work in the workbench, but i found the correct tab in dev console. I am seeing id's and i will try some of these. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

I just tried the same endpoint on Salesforce Workbench. And I was able to access the global value set from it. Can you see if host is proper?

[image]